# How to implement loss on a fully convolutional network in TensorFlow?

Tags: tensorflow, image-recognition

So I've started to implement the paper "Synthetic Data for Text Localisation in Natural Images" by Gupta et al. and I've encountered a serious problem.

The network architecture is a fully convolutional network. The final layer is basically an NxNx7 Tensor (Imagine a matrix where each cell holds 7 values). Each cell holds a P and C value. P is 6 parameters about a bounding box that should be regressed and C is the confidence.

Now I want to implement squared loss on this layer. As the paper states every cell of the final layer is a prediction, if indeed that predictor's location should contain a bounding box then the loss should be applied on all of the parameters in that predictor(or cell). If it shouldn't contain a bounding box then only regressing the confidence C should be enough.

So I should have dynamically defined separate losses in TensorFlow, how could I do that?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [tf.cond](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/cond), and write something like

```
loss = tf.cond(is_there_sthg_label, lambda: tf.add(loss1, loss2), lambda: loss2)
```

**EDIT**:

Sorry I didn't understand your problem correctly. You can make a mask of size `NxN` with value True (at runtime) on `[i, j]` if there is a bounding box, and false else. Then you compute both your losses for each cell, you get tensors `loss1` and `loss2` of shape `NxN`, and then

```
#loss1 is the loss on the confidence only, loss2 is the loss on P
loss_tensor = loss1 + tf.multiply(loss2, tf.cast(mask, loss2.dtype))
total_loss = reduce_sum(loss_tensor)
```

(this still works if you have batches of course)

Comment: Can I do this iteratively? Like taking every cell of the output layer and deciding the loss on that cell.

Comment: I'll try it out asap. Thanks this looks very promising. It's just crazy how undocumented can TF sometimes be.

Comment: Let me know if it works ! (it should; but maybe I've forgotten sthg). Yes it's hard to get answers about TF, even here, but it's changing fast, hopefully we'll get more and more documentation !